# how to convert strings in one file using a conversion table in another file with perl on a Mac?

Tags: regex, arrays, macos, perl, join

I'm trying to convert multiple lines of comma-delimited lists of values in a text file using perl.

The first file looks like this:

```
A:25, B:14, C:3
A:25, E:5
B:14, D:8, E:5
```

the second file is tab-delimited and looks like this:

```
A:25   AS363
B:14   SDD645
C:3    KF8756
D:8    LFK4523
E:5    FSE523
```

ideally i'd like the output to be comma-delimited like the original file, just everything is converted, so the output should look like this:

```
AS363, SDD645, KF8756
AS363, FSE523
SDD645, LFK4523, FSE523
```

This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my $filename1 = $ARGV[1];

open(FILE, $filename);

while (my $line = <FILE>){
          my @items = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;
             foreach my $items (@items) {
            #print "$items\n";
}
}
close FILE;

open(FILE1, $filename1);

while (my $line1 = <FILE1>) 

{

    my @ids = split /[\r\n\t]/,$line1;
    #print "$ids[1]\n";

    if (my $items==$ids[1]){
    print "$ids[1]\n";
    }
}

close FILE1;
```

it seems to fail at this point because $items in the first part is not global... if i extend the first while loop around everything, that doesn't work either, so i'm not really sure how to proceed. I've also separately just been trying to convert back into comma-delimited i'm assuming i'd have to use something like

```
join (",", ...)
```

but this doesn't seem to work either...Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the output to MATCH the first file, or just LOOK like the first file?

Comment: i think the answer is both? I want to match the first file to the second file and then convert back into the format of the first file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common approach is to read one file (the second one in this case) line by line and use a hash to save the data. As key the data to lookup and as value the data to replace. Later read the other one also line by line, split it in fields and for each one compare if exists in the hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;

die qq|Usage: perl $0 <file1> <file2>\n| unless @ARGV == 2;

open my $fh1, '<', shift or die;
open my $fh2, '<', shift or die;

while ( <$fh2> ) { 
    s/\s+$//;
    my @f = split;
    next unless @f == 2;
    $hash{ $f[0] } = $f[1];
}

while ( <$fh1> ) { 
    s/\s+$//;
    my @f = split /, /;
    for my $elem ( @f ) { 
        if ( defined $hash{ $elem } ) { 
            $elem = $hash{ $elem };
        }   
    }   
    printf qq|%s\n|, join q|, |, @f; 
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl file1 file2
```

That yields:

```
AS363, SDD645, KF8756
AS363, FSE523
SDD645, LFK4523, FSE523
```

Comment: thanks! it works but i'm going to have to study this to understand what it means!